# Image brochure with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So i am trying do something to this [link](http://www.auchan.it/volantino/volantino.php?id=3580&id_pdv=38).
The thing i manged to do is when you click on the small image it will add the class active, and if there is already an active class it will be remove.

Now what i want is when i have an image it active it will copy itself and show large version of it like the link i posted early, here is the code i did so far.

**HTML**

```
    <div class="tumbs">
        <div class="images">
            <ul>
                <li class="sp"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/0QI5Zoo.png"/></li>
                <li class="sp"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/pIy2iYG.png"/></li>
                <li class="sp"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/BjA1ljv.png"/></li>
                <li class="sp"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/BqMjYh2.png"/></li>
                <li class="sp"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/0QI5Zoo.png"/></li>
                <li class="sp"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/pIy2iYG.png"/></li>
                <li class="sp"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/BjA1ljv.png"/></li>
                <li class="sp"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/BqMjYh2.png"/></li>
                <li class="sp"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/0QI5Zoo.png"/></li>
                <li class="sp"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/pIy2iYG.png"/></li>
                <li class="sp"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/BjA1ljv.png"/></li>
                <li class="sp"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/BqMjYh2.png"/></li>
                <li class="sp"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/0QI5Zoo.png"/></li>
                <li class="sp"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/pIy2iYG.png"/></li>
                <li class="sp"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/BjA1ljv.png"/></li>
                <li class="sp"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/BqMjYh2.png"/></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div id="back"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/ukfKZyS.png"/></div>
        <div id="forward"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/rWv4vzS.png"/></div>
    </div>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //When user clicks back button the slider moves to the left
    $('#back').click(function(){
        $('.listImages').animate({left: "-=10px"}, 'fast');
    });
    //When user click forward button the slider moves to the right
    $('#forward').click(function(){
       $('.listImages').animate({left: "+=10px"}, 'fast')
    });

    //When the user clicks on a tumbnail
    $('.sp').click(function(){
        //Removes the previus active class
        $('.active').removeClass('active');
        //Add the active class to the click image
        $(this).addClass('active');
        var $largeImage = $('.active').clone();
        $('.mainImage').html($largeImage)
    });
});
```

Here is what i have done so far in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qonbLjny/3/).

How can i make the '.active' class duplicate and scale larger, i would preferbly make the large image on top like the first link i gave.

Thank you for your  help

I have updated the JsFiddle the only thing that is missing now is the list of images is not scrolling when the user clicks on the next and previous button.

Comment: Fixed it still nothing.

Comment: Your Fiddle doesn't load

Comment: Jsfiddle is not working for me either now. Give me a second to figure it out. Even home page is not working.

Comment: Ah okay, it's an internal issue their end then.

Comment: Ye. does thier home page work for you?

Comment: Updated the Jsfiddle link we new sytax. The only thing that i missing the list scrolling, how do i come by doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Syntax Error or Typo?

```
$('#back').click(function(){
    $('.images').animate({left: "-=10px"}, 'fast');
    //-^ The dot was missing!
});
```

Comment: Why are using your own code when you have a lot of plugins like [**LightBox**](http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/), etc?

Comment: No i am useing a sekelton application nothing else inside of my application accept the code in JSfiddle